# Is there a way to insert values to a table that are on a SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure that output `SYS_REFCURSOR` and insert those results in cursor into a table.

I can duplicate the `SELECT` statement as following. But is there a better approach to this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

OPEN CUR FOR
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

INSERT INTO TABLE2
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: that would be very slow, why not make it without cursor

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that a simple SQL statement:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

does the job just fine.

In other words, don't include PL/SQL (especially not cursors) into that operation.

However, in `insert`, *best practices* suggest that you should **name** all columns involved, e.g.

```
insert into table2 (id, name, address)
  select id, name, address
  from table1;
```